# .php downloads instead of opening in Chrome and FF

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, sftp, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using sftp to reach my folder on a server at uni. Both chrome and firefox would download my simple test.php instead of opening the page.

Is there any suggestion where should I look with the preferences to change this? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, okay I understand it now, my bad.

I literally mounted the server to my local machine with ssh, thus I had no server whatsoever. 
I had to reach directly with the url to open it, so I couldn't just open it from editor (VS Code - open with browser).

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver isnt passing the php file to php for processing and is just sending it on as it would any other file.  You will need to ensure that your webserver is setup to handle php correctly be it php-fpm for apache and nginx or the php module for apache

Comment: Okay, but is there something to set on my local machine? This is a university server.

Answer (score 0):

What's the webserver? You can start to read here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Comment: An Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS server. Could you please specify which section should I read?

Comment: Apache or Nginx?